Baby Rudin Chapter 2 Problem 6 Advice/Solution Verification
My friend and I are learning reading Baby Rudin currently and we both have reached the problem set for chapter 2, and my friend asks me to solve this problem and here is my solution:
Original Problem: Let $E'$ be the set of all limit points of a set $E$. Prove that $E'$ is closed. Prove that $ E$ and $\overline{E}$ have the same limit points. (Recall that $\overline{E} = E \cup E'$.) Do $ E $ and $E'$ always have the same limit points?
Let $ x \in E'.$ If we have any neighborhood N(x), it contains a $x' \in E'$ with $ x \ne x' $.
By Theorem 2.22, we have:
$
(\bigcup_{\alpha} E_{\alpha})^{c} = \bigcap_{\alpha} (E_{\alpha}^{c}) \Longleftrightarrow 
N \setminus \{x\} = N \cap \{x\}^c
$
This is open, which implies the containment of a neighborhood $N'(x')$.
$N' $ intersects $ E $ since $ x' \in E' \implies N $ does too. Then that implies that ( x \in E' ) because this is the same for every limit point. We get the conclusion that ( E' ) is closed.
Since $E \subseteq \overline{E} $, a limit point belonging to one will belong to the other. If $ x $ is a limit point of $\overline{E} = E \cup E'$, $ N_{\frac{1}{n}} (x) $ must intersect either $ E $ for an infinite number of values of $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, or $ E' $ for an infinite number of values of $ n $ (anything otherwise leads to a contradiction).
We then see, since
$
N_{\epsilon} (x) \subseteq N_{\epsilon'} (x) \text{, when } \epsilon < \epsilon',
$
All neighborhoods of ( x ) intersect either $ E $ or $ E' $. So in both cases $ x \in E' $ $\blacksquare$
For the third part of this problem the answer is no
My friend said my proof is incorrect, although I believe it is correct, so I would like to know if this solution is incorrect or correct, and how to fix it if it is the former; thank you if you decide to answer my question

"My friend said my proof is incorrect": where? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

@AnneBauval there was no specification, he just disagreed with my proof entirely; and for your 1st comment, it is problem 6 from Chapter 2 of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis Parts A & B

I added the problem to the question

Good! Now please restrict to one of the 3 questions, and (again) tell us precisely which step in the proof is in doubt (this site is meant to help, not to be used as a proof-checker).

@AnneBauval As I said, he never specified, he said that the proof is wrong, all parts of it; and I would like to know if he is correct or incorrect

As I quoted, this question is too broad.

In the first paragraph, you do not know that $x'$ is in $E'$. The second paragraph is meaningless. The error in the first paragraph propagates to the fourth. Anyway, the fourth paragraph is meaningless even if we ignore that error. You seem to be saying that your nonargument implies $x\in E'$ and therefore $E'$ is closed. But you assumed that $x\in E'$ to begin with, so you really haven't done anything so far.
